# SHOW tables with zero records in SSRS Tablix with RowGroups

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

I have a Tablix and a Dataset  is binded to the tablix. One of the column in the dataset is used as "RowGroups"  and a sub table is designed to show the results for each Rowgroups in a seperate table .

While running the report it is appearing correctly , but one issue noticed is that if we choose a SELECT statement with q where condition as

```
  WHERE RowGroupID IN(xx,yy,zz)  group by RowGroupID
```

And the result set contain values for xx and yy only and no records for zz . 
So while rendering the report 2 sub tables will be created in report for xx and yy but no tables or no information for RowGroupId zz

What settings or properties i should set to shoow the RowGroupID's with 0 records in a Tablix with RowGroups

Answer (score 1):

There is no settings/properties to makes it shows the tablix rows that there aren't. Your result set contains 2 rows and not 3, so 2 rows are shown.

You should change your query instead, to make it return result set with all 3 rows.

You can do it by left joining your current result set to the 3 fixed rows containing xx, yy and zz.

Here is my example.

I have a table of natural numbers `dbo.Nums` that has no negative numbers, but suppose I want to have a row with -1 included in my result set.

If I just filter my table like this: `where nums.n in (-1,2,3)` I'll miss the row with `-1`.

For fixing that I left join my result from `dbo.Nums` with fixed rows containing `-1`, `2`, `3`, so my `where` condition becomes `on` condition like this:

```
with cte as
(
select *
from (values (-1), (2), (3))v(n)
)
select *
from cte c
     left join dbo.nums nums
        on c.n = nums.n
           and nums.n in (-1,2,3);
```

[image]